# zend modules models

Tags: zend-framework, module, models

My application setup with 2 modules admin and default
I test the controller which works fine on modules

but the models doesnt work

I created a model application\modules\admin\models\User.php

```
<?php

class Admin_Model_User{
}
```

inside the controller

```
$user = new Admin_Model_User();
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_User'
>   not found

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essentially, you need 2 lines in the application.ini file;

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

Then, for each module, you need a module bootstrap file:

File: myproject/application/modules/{modulename}/Bootstrap.php

```
<?php

class {Modulename}_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
}
```

(Yes, it is an empty class.)

Further details are at http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/bootstrapping-modules-in-zf-1-8/.

Comment: I can make non-default model works, but when I create a Default_Model_{Model}, which still get the error , any idea why?
I do have Bootstrap.php in my /application/modules/default/

Answer (score 1):

Configure an autoloader so that the framework can map your class prefix `Admin_Model` to the corresponding source path. This is not done automatically.

I suggest reading the [part on models](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart/create-a-model-and-database-table) of the [Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart), which explains in detail how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an autoloader?

If you do you should change the class name (or path) to reflect the path (or class name)

Models <> Model

You should have

Admin_Model_User in admin/model/user.php

or

Admin_Models_User in admin/models/user.php.