# zend_form config problem

Tags: zend-framework, zend-config

I have a structure like follows:

```
/application
.....
--/modules
----/structure
------/controllers
--------/indexController.php
------/forms
--------/Department.php //here class Structure_Form_Department extends Zend_Form
```

in indexController.php

```
...
public function saveAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form = new Structure_Form_Department();//<-- error
....
}
```

and i get error

> Fatal error: Class 'Structure_Form_Department' not found

when try to `zf enable form module` - receive :

```
An Error Has Occurred                         
 This project already has forms enabled.
```

i think this is a config-like problem... but do not understand what i need to do...

**EDIT 1**

found good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836447/zend-modules-models)

but for some way zend starts repeat executing `_init...` functions from default bootstrap.php....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was also facing a similar problem few months ago and I got the solution by writing following code :

### In application.ini

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Structure_"
```

### In Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader=new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                'namespace' => 'Structure',
                'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Structure'
            ));
    }
```

### And at the index.php

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Please let me know if it doesn't works.....

Comment: `/application/bootstrap.php` or `/application/modeules/structure/bootstrap.php` ?

Comment: does not helps ... _Warning: include_once(Structure/Form/Department.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory..._

Comment: ok then... after many hrs spent on this. there is good enough to add `_initAutoload()` to Bootstrap.php but you point me to wrong path. the correct one is `dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'modules'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'structure'` (according to lowercase 's'). but thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding `Application` in-front of `Structure_Form_Department` will work.

ie

```
Application_Structure_Form_Department()
```

Or you may want to tell in the config.ini the from `appnamespace = "Application"` to `appnamespace = ''`.

I have some piece of code in github. You can see how the modules work.

```
$contactForm = new Contact_Form_Contact();
```

Name of form is

```
class contact_Form_Contact extends Zend_Form
```

All codes over github. Check it out .

https://github.com/harikt/blog/blob/master/application/modules/contact/controllers/IndexController.php

https://github.com/harikt/blog/blob/master/application/modules/contact/forms/Contact.php

Comment: What's the name of the form ? I mean class X_Y_Z extends Zend_Form .

Comment: like here `Fatal error: Class 'Structure_Form_Department' not found` =)

Comment: I guess you are calling the form from controller like `Structure_Form_Department` . Now show me the name of the form you have made which extends the Zend_Form . Is it same ? Else see some code over here https://github.com/harikt/blog/blob/master/application/modules/contact/forms/Contact.php

Comment: form was created by zend tool `class Structure_Form_Department extends Zend_Form`