# Zend Command Line can't find model in modules

Tags: zend-framework, module, find, command-line-interface, models

Sorry for my English, but please help me. How can i find model in modules. I used Zend Framework 1.12 and i run php file in command line. Example code:

```
//file located in project/scripts/test.php
<?php

//ini_set("display_errors","1"); ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
// Initialize the application path and autoloading
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', $argv[1]);

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library',
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// Initialize Zend_Application
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
); 

//this model i can find
$sendQueueModel = new Application_Model_DbTable_SendQueue();
//but this i can't. Managers - this is module in project
$managersMOdel = new Managers_Model_Company();
```

Comment: Check if this helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836447/zend-modules-models/1837722#1837722

Answer (score 0):

That module is not loading thats why you cant access models. In normal way we add autoloader in `Bootstap.php`, here you should try the same code to load it. (after initializing `Zend_Application`)

```
  $autoLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                'namespace' => 'Managers',
                'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/managers'
            ));
```